Define a re-usable path with its own anchors defined by a start and end point
I'm a little lost here, so forgive me if this makes less sense or it's less specific than it should :)
I'm trying to define a path to use as a square bracket in diagrams. The behavior I am looking for is similar to what happens in this minimal code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\raise}
\setlength{\raise}{3 pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(first) at (0,0){};
    \node(last) at (1,0){};

    \coordinate(A) at ($(first)-(0,\raise)$);
    \coordinate(B) at ($(A)-(0,\raise)$);
    \coordinate(D) at ($(last)-(0,\raise)$);
    \coordinate(C) at ($(D)-(0,\raise)$);
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);

    % Needs anchors so I can place nodes like this later.
    \node at ($(B)!0.75!(C)$){x};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Where the first and last nodes will be two nodes/coordinates/positions whatever. I'd like to draw this by passing the names of the nodes and the raise parameter. I don't even know where to start or what I should be using. It looks like I need to dive deep into the \pgfpath commands, which I can do, once I figure out the minimal structure I should be using. Ideally, this path would have anchors so that I can add nodes later, like the last node "x" in the code.
After I figure this out I'll have to figure out how to make it so that the direction of the brackets is not hard coded, that is, the code automagically figures out how to place the coordinates A,B,C,D so that the bracket "raises" are perpendicular to the line between the first and last point.
I found this answer that is similar to what I'm asking for in the sense that they can pass parameters and this answer that gives hints as to how to add anchors. But there's a lot of distractors and my level of understanding of \pgf... stuff is incrementally above zero.
Per @MS-SPO's question below, this is a draft diagram I'm working on:


Welcome. // I'd like to better understand how you would use such diagrams later. Perhaps you can create a mock-up using some bitmap drawings and add that to your question? Solutions depend a little bit on what you are going to do with it. Thank you // You may want to have a look at the \pic statement, which you can make accepting parameters.

I second @MS-SPO's comment. Only nodes have anchors, paths don't. Maybe you want something like the ud path operation: \draw (0,0) ud[ud distance=\raise] node {x} (1,0); would draw such a path and place the x along the that path.

Alright, now that I see your picture, an alternative solution would be to use a normal straight paths with harpooned arrow tips at their end. This allows a bit more customization about how the hooks at the end look like. We will need a bit math to figure out the offset but that is easily doable. You just need to place a coordinate along the -- part (and not a node) so that you can reference it later for the other arrow paths.

Nice idea. I think the intention is to adopt e.g. from here: https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#sec-16.5.1 . See e.g. Straight Barb[right] with length set to 0.

Those are good comments! I had looked into those at some point but none seemed to have exactly the shape I need. My question, however, is more on how to create a template for that shape (and define my anchors wherever I want). For instance, I may want to the \raise parameter is. I have other shapes that I use very regularly that I could use this approach for.

Why do you think you want a shape? What would its anchors be? There are infinite positions between two points but there can only be a finite amount of anchors. You can already use the $ syntax to access all points between …

Here is an example, demonstrating how to develop a desired functionality step by step, following Qrrbrbirlbel's suggestion.
Summary:

1. Start simple
The most simple thing you can try is drawing a line with arrow tips. Here I used:

polar coordinates for the end point
specified a relative movement
put a node with useful anchor point as a label before ending the path action by ;

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    aw/.style={anchor=west},    
 ]
    % ~~~ start simple ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<->]          (0,2) -- +(35:2) node[aw] {start simple};

2. Replace tips
Replace the symbols < and > by a useful tip from the arrows.meta library. Note that width will function as what you call raise. (BTW, using names with preloaded meaning is a safe way to hinder inventive thinking ... so drop raise as soon as possible.)
    % ~~~ replace both tips ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[{Bar[right,width=5mm]}-{Bar[left,width=5mm]}] 
                        (0,1) -- +(35:2) node[aw] {replaced tips};

3. Refacter those clumsy tips
Now, Tikz is implemented in TeX; so using \def instead of preferred \newcommand from LaTeX may be tolerable here (in fact, \newcommand doesn't always cooperate with Tikz, while \def seems to). Let's introduce two shortcuts for the asymmetric tips:
\def\brr{{Bar[right,width=5mm]}}
\def\brl{{Bar[left,width=5mm]}}
...
    % ~~~ use \def-ined shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[\brr-\brl]    (0,0) -- +(35:2) node[aw] {using defs};

4. Time for your movable point
Let's introduce a named coordinate, which you can use later. And let's test, it's accessible:
    % ~~~ intermediate point ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[\brr-\brl]    (0,-1) -- coordinate[pos=.8] (A) +(35:2) node[aw] {putting A};  
    \draw[red] (A) -- +(-23:1.5) node[aw] {starting at A};

5. Time to absorb by an other macro
Let's put the drawing inside a \newcommand sqbr (square bracket), which takes 5 parameters:

1+2 for absolute positions
3 for the relative position (0 <= pos <= 1)
4 named coordinate
5 your "raise" (specify units! {8mm} will work, while {0.8} won't)

By NOT-including the ; inside \sqbr you still can put nodes as label, as seen above. And let's test, if we can access both (A) and (B). BTW, one tip is now replaced by an other \def, which takes 1 parameter, your "raise" :
\def\brlw#1{{Bar[left,width=#1]}}

\newcommand\sqbr[5]{% 1: start, 2: end, 3: pos, 4: namedCoord, 5: raise
\draw[\brr-\brlw{#5}] (#1) -- coordinate[pos=#3] (#4) (#2)}
...
    % ~~~ absorbed by a macro ~~~~~~~
    \sqbr{0,-2}{2,-1.5}{.3}{B}{10mm} node[aw] {via newcommand};
    \draw[teal] (B) -- +(-5:.7);
    
    \draw[dashed, ->, orange] (A) -- (B);

6. Final remark
This approach takes the lines end points as reference AND puts the tips (ticks) as needed. You could also reverse this, use coordinates as the tips end points and shift the line coordinates accordingly. Will be a matter of preference and use-ability.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\def\brr{{Bar[right,width=5mm]}}
\def\brl{{Bar[left,width=5mm]}}
\def\brlw#1{{Bar[left,width=#1]}}

\newcommand\sqbr[5]{% 1: start, 2: end, 3: pos, 4: namedCoord, 5: raise
\draw[\brr-\brlw{#5}] (#1) -- coordinate[pos=#3] (#4) (#2)}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    aw/.style={anchor=west},    
 ]
    % ~~~ start simple ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<->]          (0,2) -- +(35:2) node[aw] {start simple};
    
    % ~~~ replace both tips ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[{Bar[right,width=5mm]}-{Bar[left,width=5mm]}] 
                        (0,1) -- +(35:2) node[aw] {replaced tips};

    % ~~~ use \def-ined shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[\brr-\brl]    (0,0) -- +(35:2) node[aw] {using defs};


    % ~~~ intermediate point ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[\brr-\brl]    (0,-1) -- coordinate[pos=.8] (A) +(35:2) node[aw] {putting A};  
    \draw[red] (A) -- +(-23:1.5) node[aw] {starting at A};
    
    % ~~~ absorbed by a macro ~~~~~~~
    \sqbr{0,-2}{2,-1.5}{.3}{B}{10mm} node[aw] {via newcommand};
    \draw[teal] (B) -- +(-5:.7);
    
    \draw[dashed, ->, orange] (A) -- (B);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is great and instructional, thank you so much @MS-SPO
